# convert one single column to multiple columns in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to convert a single column to multiple columns using 
grep -v '^\s*$' $1| pr -ts" " --columns $2
but I get this error: 
pr: page width too narrow

could someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't fully clear to me. Maybe you can provide some sample input data as well. If you want to convert 1 column to multiple columns xargs command can be used.

xargs -n10 --> will convert 1 column to 10 i.e. it will take 10 rows and make them one.

BR,

Comment: i have a text file like this:
1 
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
.
.
.
I want to convert it to this:
1 2 3 . .
1 2 3 . .
1 2 3 . .
but the file that I have has too many numbers, ( want to convert it to a file with 25000 columns !).

Comment: Hi Sorry, still in the input data isn't clear. Are you saying the input file has 25000 rows and you want to convert it to 25000 columns?

Comment: awk '{ printf("%-10s ",$0); if(NR%3==0) printf("\n");}' with this you can convert every Nth row into Nth column. Aforementioned is for converting 3rd row into 3rd column. Hope this helps